# FTPs For Each Command

Tags: batch-file, ftp, ftps

I am using FTPs.exe (move it freely) and want to do the following:

- Move each file in a directory on the FTP site to a Downloaded Directory on the FTP site.
- Delete the file moved from the original pick up directory.

I have constructed a do statement (below) to try and do this but it is not working as expected. Is the issue that the "Do" command is not supported? Or have I just written the logic incorrectly?

```
    open [Domain]
    [username]
    [password]
    lcd [LocalPath]

    prompt

    cd [FTPPath]
    for /r %%i in (*) do (get %%i && cd [FTPPath]/downloaded && put %%i && cd [FTPPath] delete %%i)

    quit
    close
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Batch file commands cannot be used in an FTP script - which has it's own set of commands.  As an aside, FTPs.exe isn't a default Windows command.

Comment: I guess the comment I have off the back of that would be whether it is possible to do this in FTP script? I cannot see anything that would be able to do the above.

Comment: Look into third party FTP programs - you might find that one can move the files in the server rather than downloading and then uploading them all, which is the only option with `FTP.EXE`.  That would require creating a list of the files in one FTP session and generating an FTP script on-the-fly and then doing the downloading/uploading.